# Using Div as value for form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use a div element to submit value instead defaults button and input element into form the code look like this.

**index.php**

```
    <form action="foo.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <div id="btn" name="Siren" value="Ifrit" style="width:20px; height:20px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
    </form>

    <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
         document.getElementById('form1').submit().value;
    }, false);

    </script>
```

**foo.php**

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Siren'])){ echo $_POST['Siren'];}
```

above code doesn't work like i missing something.

how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use a div instead of an input?

Comment: Why are you using a div instead of a button? A div is the element you use when HTML doesn't have a suitable element, but HTML has button.

Comment: i want to make my code straight-forward to minimize size html. i know i can achieve it with label element but it make the code mess. so i want to using a div directly. thank you

Comment: How on earth does using a div make your code "straight-forward"? It forces you to write a big pile of JavaScript to simulate all the things button does by default! That makes the HTML bigger and has the opposite effect to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: *CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.* — http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html

Comment: what is `submit().value`?

Comment: @Quentin do you forget id, class? it gives identifier for specific element to specific event. so it will not make all things to be button. i think it posibble cause javascript power. i just dont know that. hehe

Comment: @jarwobangun — The point is that a button is a button and you shouldn't use CSS and JavaScript to make a div act like a button.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a hidden textfield?

```
<input type="hidden" name="Siren" value="iFrit" />
```

You could even place it inside your div:

```
<div id="btn" style="width:20px; height:20px; border:1px solid black;">
     <input type="hidden" name="Siren" value="iFrit" />
</div>
```

Comment: i have use so far but the code looks mess. so i want straight-forward code using div act as button and or input element event.

Comment: I think we are kinda getting in a semantic discussion here ;)
Define a mess?

If you use a button element for a button, and a hidden field to sent hidden form data... I agree you have more HTML than just a div but EVERY dev out here will understand directly whats going on and it works directly out of the box.

If you use a single div as both a button and a form field, for sure you are using less HTML, but you need javascript to get it working and alot of devs will not understand whats going on without doing some investigation....

So,. yeah define a mess ;)

Comment: i think it will not mess developer and user. we can look getAtrribute that make custom attribute has value. its just about time someone reveal the script and browser adopt it. so every element can be act as part of form. so far i'm using div inside button element with property transparent border none and div position absolute to give what i want. yeah but it still not straight-forward solution. i hopes there's guru will show-up here hehe

Comment: If you really want too I could give you a head start, its just I have never seen a reason to do so.
    A div does not have a "name" or "value" argument comform the HTML standaard, you can however use "data-name" and "data-value" if you really have to. By manually manipulating the form object within javascript you can append the value you stored in the div. But it basicly comes down to the same thing, you are now adding form fields in javascript the same way as the above example is doing in html.

Answer (score 1):

On form submit event, pass the value/html of the div to an hidden input field, and the server will catch up that input value.

Has was said by Alex, only input, select,textarea are passed to the server side.

Comment: The form won't have a submit event. The div isn't a submit button do it won't trigger one.

Comment: ok, just use your click event before you submit the form.

Comment: @Quentin div with input hidden inside is posibble by give the div a click event but it look mess and consume size content

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp .

You can't use a div like a classic button, it's not its role. Infact you can't access to a div value (? the html inside ?) from another page like you wrote

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Siren'])){ echo $_POST['Siren'];}
```

Using CSS you can syle the classic form elements (input, texarea, button ...) as you prefer.

---

**updated after the comments below**
1.

> old system so far we can approach. 
>   `<div><input type="hidden>Content</div>.`

I can't undestand this example, what's the problem with input hidden?
It do its work, you can simply write:

```
<input type="hidden" name="the name" value="content">
```

2.

> `<button type="submit style="background:transparent; border:none; padding:0;"><div>Content</div></button>.`

Why you put a div inside a button?
however you can, for example, assign the css code to a class and put it in in the header section or better in an external file, then you can simply:

```
<button type="submit class="myClass">Content</button>
```

3.

> `<input type="hidden" id="label"> <label for="label"><div>Content</div></label>`

I can't understand , why you should add a label to an input hidden?
(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=597650)

if you want to understand a little better about what the field tag do and how to use it, you should look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: by default. it says its imposibble. but with javascript everything is posibble. we just don't know that.

Comment: ok, with javascript _almost_ everything can be done ... but to use a div as a field of a form, has not a practical utility.
Give us some example of what you "earn" using a div instead a button/field/...

Comment: less code when design a site with an list item and more viewable. ex. old system so far we can approach. 1. <div><input type="hidden>Content</div>. 2. <button type="submit style="background:transparent; border:none; padding:0;"><div>Content</div></button>. 3. <input type="hidden" id="label"> <label for="label"><div>Content</div></label>. can u look how a mess the code? now if we can just like this <div id="btn" name="post" value="Leviathan">Content</div> u can see the bytes size and which the more viewable?

Comment: ok, i answer start from 2. the div should have position:absolute property style. if button set transparent and border and padding 0. the content inside div will be invisible so it should have position:absolute property and if button don't have transparent and border and padding 0, your content inside button will like a button view there's border bottom and right when clicked. 3. it just a others ways to achieve this thing. the best so far is with button. back to conclusion why i want div can act as part of form is less code and viewable. ex <div id="btn" name="post" value="Shiva">

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your examples; can you put your full  working example code in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ )?